# Error in creating push notifications in Kindle Devices?

Tags: android, push-notification, kindle-fire, amazon-device-messaging

I am creating push notifications for my application on `Kindle devices`. I am following all the procedure they explained in the documentation, but still getting this error:

`SampleADMMessageHandler:onRegistrationError INVALID_SENDER`

I had `api_key` in assets folder and added jar file as well. I am using my account in Amazon dashboard. I had tested in kindle HD device with latest version. My device also registered with kindle.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

INVALID_SENDER can be received during ADM registration for a couple of reasons. Let’s try the easy one first:

1. Did you check for whitespace? ADM won’t recognize an API Key if it contains any white spaces or line breaks (please refer to: https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/adm/integrating-app.html#Asset ).
2. It could be an issue with the API key. To generate an API key, you should have entered the package name and the MD5 signature of the certificate you are using to sign your app. Did you do this? If you did, are you sure it’s entered correctly in your app? If there was a typo in the key, that would cause INVALID_SENDER at run time.

The md5 fingerprint of the app’s signing certificate is important in this process too. While extracting the md5 fingerprint of the apk, check that you entered the alias and password of the .keystore (the one you’re using to sign the apk) correctly. Check out this link for more information : https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/adm/credentials.html#Getting

Comment: I had followed all the steps you explain in amazon forums. now i am able to get Register ID from android application, and i am looking for creating this for adobe flash application even for that also i had completed the steps clearly. still i am in state of not able to receive registration Id ( even though it's not calling ADMReceiver call backs ) what will be the problem can you tell me solution for this..

Comment: Are you going to release your app as an Adobe AIR app? The reason I ask is that Adobe stopped supporting Flash for Android in August of 2012, and Flash is not supported on Kindle Fire devices running ICS. (Currently, ADM only works on Kindle Fire devices.)

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy any luck to resolve this issue ?